# Mac Excel won't recognize Spanish/Portuguese accents (UTF8 or ANSI)

Tags: ms-office, internationalization, encoding

I'm working with Excel to open a delimited (tabbed) txt file that contains Portuguese and Spanish accents. As you can see below, in the third row there is a title "Último Año" that is correct.

[image]

However when I import the file into Excel the text is misinterpreted as "Ãšltimo AÃ±o".

[image]

The correct codepage would be Unicode UTF-8 or ANSI. I tried several options, like using the import file options from Excel to select UTF-8 (and other formats) but the result is always weird.

[image]

**Does anybody know how to interpret/display the correct latin accents on Mac Excel?**

Comment: UTF-8 https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl

Comment: @Buscar yeah that one, I just need Excel to use it...

Comment: does it works if you try to Insert a Symbol and choose yours ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 yes the input is fine, I can type all characters, no problem. Its an import issue. Maybe I can create an autocorrect table for the weird entries and run it as a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several bumps in the wall I figure out this Terminal command (Shell Script) that will convert properly the files from UTF-8 for Latin 1:

`iconv -f UTF-8 -t LATIN1 </path/sourceFile.txt >/path/destinationFile.txt`

Oddly enough, the Finder preview won't display the correct characters and TextEdit won't even open the file. But Excel recognize everything, which is fine for me.